# How can I transform my calculation into a function?

Tags: matrix, code-review

I have written the following `code`, which serves my purpose. However, I like to have a Mathematica function such as

```
Multiplier[ioMatrix_] := Module[{...}, ...]
```

to integrate all the steps in the following code.

```
ClearAll[row, col, ioMatrix, ioMatrixExt1, colStd, backwardTC, multiplier];
SeedRandom[132];
row = 10;
col = 15;
sector = 6;
ioMatrix = RandomInteger[5, {row, col}];  (*create a matrix*)
ioMatrixExt1 = Join[ioMatrix, {ConstantArray[1,row].ioMatrix}]; (*add 
   the vector of column-sums to the last row*)
colStd = N@Table[Flatten[
   ioMatrixExt1[[i ;; i]]/ioMatrixExt1[[row + 1 ;; row + 1]]], {i, 
   1, row}];  (*standardize each column with its column-sum and drop the last row*)
backwardTC = Take[colStd, sector, sector];  (*select a submatrix from the  
   column-wise standardized matrix*)
multiplier = Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sector] - backwardTC]  (*final output*)
```

Comment: Are you asking someone to do the work for you? It seems all you have to do is drop the code into `Module`....

Comment: @MichaelE2: My intention is not asking someone to do the work for me. The code I developed is already working fine. I thought that there is a way to shorten and making the operations more efficient. For example, instead of using `Do` loops, matrix operations will be more efficient. That was my intention.

Comment: I did not think you were asking for someone to do the work, but the question does not even hint at anything else, esp. the things you put in your comment.  Perhaps you would revise the question to include your intention?  The tag [tag:code-review] seems appropriate in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2: You are right that I could not clearly express my intention in my question. I should add a new tag to the question.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed because the OP has made a "simple mistake". There are several non-trivial mistakes in the posted code. The OP really need an answer or anwers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fn[M_?MatrixQ, sec_Integer] := (
  (#/Tr[#] & /@ N[M\[Transpose]])\[Transpose]
    // Take[#, sec, sec] &
    // Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sec] - #] &
 )

fn[ioMatrix, sector] == multiplier
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: I was after the type of answer you provided above. A single function does all.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Glad I could help.  Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work much harder than it needs to. If my understanding of what you are trying to is correct, all you need is:

```
row = 10;
col = 15;
sector = 6;
SeedRandom[132]; ioMatrix = RandomInteger[5, {row, col}]
```

> ```
> {{5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 3}, 
>  {0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 0}, 
>  {1, 5, 0, 1, 4, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5}, 
>  {0, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4}, 
>  {2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2}, 
>  {1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 0, 5, 5}, 
>  {0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3}, 
>  {3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3}, 
>  {0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3}}
> ```

```
multiplier[ioMatrix_, sector_] :=
  Module[{rows, colStd, backwardTC}, 
    rows = Dimensions[ioMatrix][[1]];
    (*standardize each column with its column sum*)
    colStd =
      With[{m = Transpose @ ioMatrix, s = ConstantArray[1, rows].ioMatrix}, 
        MapThread[#1 /#2 &, {m, s}, 1] // Transpose // N];
    (*select a submatrix from the column-wise standardized matrix*)
    backwardTC = Take[colStd, sector, sector]; 
    Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sector] - backwardTC]]

multiplier[ioMatrix, sector]
```

> ```
> {{2.01352, 0.562086, 0.437948, 0.431361, 0.56428, 0.528142}, 
>  {0.0862825, 1.23347, 0.140942, 0.0502556, 0.156757, 0.149522}, 
>  {0.268471, 0.375109, 1.11532, 0.138224, 0.289638, 0.184703}, 
>  {0.179151, 0.274718, 0.281898, 1.19849, 0.353205, 0.265747}, 
>  {0.442858, 0.25176, 0.191884, 0.193985, 1.27302, 0.362074}, 
>  {0.315345, 0.350103, 0.238641, 0.274887, 0.318653, 1.33147}}
> ```

Comment: `colStd` gives an error stating `Objects of unequal length`. The division of matrix elements to its column sums has a problem.

Comment: @TugrulTemel. Sorry about that. Somehow I copied a bad early attempt at solving the problem from my notebook. I have edited my answer so it now shows the version of the code I intended to post.